# Java swing application throws NullPointerException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" for unkown reason

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, nullpointerexception, awt

I created a console application in Java, using the swing package but it has an issue. First of all how the application works:

The application opens a JFrame (Console class) on the screen, which contains a JPanel (ConsoleScreen class). The JPanel only contains a non-editable, scrollable JTextArea. The console has 3 different methods that can be called programmatically:
1: print (prints text to the console)
2: input (takes inline input from the console and returns it)
3: empty (empties the console)

More info about the input method:

When the input method is invoked, it makes the text area temporarily editable, and allows the user to enter inline input. However, it disables them from formatting the rest of the text on the text area (by using an instance of the TextAreaDocumentFilter class). While waiting for input, the program invokes the sleep(long millis) method on the main thread repeatedly, in order to waste as little CPU time as possible. In addittion, the text area has a DocumentListener, and once the user clicks enter, in order to move to the next line, the interrupt() method is called on the main thread, to make the program stop waiting for input, and the text area becomes non-editable again. Then, the inline input given from the user is returned.

Problem:

The problem has to do with the input method. Basically, whenever I invoke that method and take input from the console, everything seems to be working fine (the correct result is displayed on the console and the correct input is returned). However, in the meantime, a NullPointerException is thrown in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" almost everytime the program takes input from the console, and I cannot understand why. I tried enclosing many different parts of the program inside try/catch statements, but the exceptions were still thrown as if nothing had changed. Moreover, I tried adding print statements almost everywhere in the program, in a desperate attempt to find the source of the errors, but it was no use.

Could you please help me solve this, or at least tell me why it is happening? Here is the code for the Console, a test program, and one of the most common stack traces I get. Try running the test program, and see the errors yourself. Thank you for your attention!

Console class:

```
package interpreter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

final class Console extends JFrame{
    
    
    
    private ConsoleScreen screen;
    
    

    Console(){

        setTitle("Console");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setUndecorated(false);
        
        screen = new ConsoleScreen();
        add(screen);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    void print(String text) {   
        screen.print(text);
    }
    


    String input() {    
        return screen.input();
    }

    
    
    void empty() {
        screen.empty();
    }

}
```

ConsoleScreen class:

```
package interpreter;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;

final class ConsoleScreen extends JPanel{
    
    
    
    Thread mainThread;
    
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private DocumentListener textAreaDocumentListener;
    private TextAreaDocumentFilter textAreaDocumentFilter;
    
    private boolean takingInput;
    private int inputStartIndex = 0; /*text index after which input is taken */
    
    
    
    ConsoleScreen(){
        
        mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        textAreaDocumentFilter = new TextAreaDocumentFilter();
        textAreaDocumentListener = new TextAreaDocumentListener();
        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        fillScreen();
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    void fillScreen() {
        
        textArea = new JTextArea("");
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        textArea.setCaretColor(Color.WHITE);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(textAreaDocumentListener);
        ((AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(textAreaDocumentFilter);
        
        
        
        JScrollPane textAreaScroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textAreaScroller.setBorder(null);
        
        add(textAreaScroller);
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    //prints text to the console
    void print(String text) {
        
        textArea.append(text);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
        inputStartIndex += text.length();
        
    }
    


    //takes one line of input from the console
    String input() {
        
        takingInput = true;
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        
        while(takingInput) {
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(999999999);
            }catch(InterruptedException e) {break;}
            
        }
        
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        
        String inputText = textArea.getText().substring(inputStartIndex, textArea.getText().length() - 1);
        inputStartIndex = textArea.getText().length();
        
        return inputText;
        
    }

    
    
    //empties the console
    void empty() {
        textArea.setText("");
        inputStartIndex = 0;
    }
    
    



    /* does not allow the user to format the text behind the inputStartIndex */
    private class TextAreaDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        public void insertString(final FilterBypass fb, final int offset, final String string, final AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (!takingInput || offset >= inputStartIndex) 
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }



        public void remove(final FilterBypass fb, final int offset, final int length) throws BadLocationException {
            if (!takingInput || offset >= inputStartIndex) 
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
        }



        public void replace(final FilterBypass fb, final int offset, final int length, final String text, final AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (!takingInput || offset >= inputStartIndex) 
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }

    }
    
    
    
    
    
    /* makes the program stop receiving input once the user has moved to the next line of the console */
    private class TextAreaDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            if(takingInput) {
                
                String text = textArea.getText();
                if(text.length() > inputStartIndex && text.charAt(text.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                    mainThread.interrupt();
                    takingInput = false;
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            insertUpdate(e);
        }

    };

}
```

Test class:

```
package interpreter;

class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Console console = new Console();
        String input = "";
        
        do {
            
            console.print("Enter a string: ");
            input = console.input();
            console.print("String entered: " + input + "\n\n");
            
        }while(!input.equals("END"));
        
    }

}
```

One common stack trace I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.getHighlighter()" because "host" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView$WrappedLine.paint(WrappedPlainView.java:716)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.BoxView.paintChild(BoxView.java:162)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(BoxView.java:434)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.paint(WrappedPlainView.java:501)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(BasicTextUI.java:1530)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(BasicTextUI.java:759)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(BasicTextUI.java:917)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(BasicTextUI.java:896)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: All Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. If you don't you can have random issues. Try using a `SwingWorker` as your background Thread and then "publish" the input to your GUI. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. The section on `Tasks that have interim results` shows how to use the SwingWorker.

Comment: What camickr said.  Proper threading considerations aren’t just polish, it’s a necessity.  Also, regarding your use of `takingInput` by different threads, I suggest you read [this short example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) in the Java Language Specification.  You probably want to declare takingInput as `volatile`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I don't exactly understand what you mean. I read the tutorial you sent me, and also looked at Oracle's page about SwingWorker, but I still do not know how to use it to fix my program.  What do you mean by saying "Try using a SwingWorker as your background Thread and then "publish" the input to your GUI". I'm sorry, I have a lot of trouble understanding mutlithreading :/

Comment: Tip: add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are attempting to do. I'm not sure if my suggestion applies. All I know is that updates to Swing components need to be done on the EDT. A Thread should NOT update a Swing component.  Gui's are meant to be event driven. You generally don't have an outer "do while" loop. Instead the main() method should just create the GUI and display it. In your case you would then add the prompt to the text area. Then the GUI should just sit there and wait for input. When a "\n" character is received you then to "something". If the text is "END" you do your final processing.

Comment: If the text something else you add the text to your console and then prompt for more text. So you may not need a SwingWorker or any Thread. You just need to respond to user events as they type.

Comment: The Console is a actually a part of a bigger project, a programming language I created. The language has three io commands (print, input and empty). When you run some code in that language, the console immediately pops up. The output is loaded there, and input can be taken from there. The main() method with the do-while loop is just a test program. Anyway, I will try to modify the program a little bit so that component updates are  only made inside the EDT thread. Thanks, again!

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix the error.  I modified the ConsoleScreen class so that the textArea is always editable (and doesn't become editable and non-editable inside the input() method). Also,  I created another volatile boolean variable named "modifyingConsole" that turns true when the print(), or the empty() method is called, and modified the TextAreaDocumentFilter, so that these methods can properly modify the text area despite the inputStartIndex. Thank you for all your help! :)